# Replace NaN values with third to last value

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am new to working with Python and have the following problem with my calculations.
I have a table which contains `NaN` values.
The `NaN` values always occur at night, because no solar radiation can be measured there.
I want to replace all `NaN` values from a night with the value 4 hours before sunset.
I already tried to use the `Ffill` command, but since I don't need the last value before the `NaN` values, it doesn't work unfortunately.

For example:

```
a=[0.88, 0.84, 0.26, 0.50, 1.17, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.73, 0.81]
```

The successive `NaN` values should all have the value `0.84`.
The list should therefore look like this:

```
a=[0.88, 0.84, 0.26, 0.50, 1.17, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.73, 0.81]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use a dataframe, please update your post with a sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a `shift`ed and `ffill`ed version of the original series and then just using that to fill in the nulls of the original data:

```
In [231]: s.fillna(s.shift(3).mask(s.isnull()).ffill())
Out[231]:
0     0.88
1     0.84
2     0.26
3     0.50
4     1.17
5     0.84
6     0.84
7     0.84
8     0.84
9     0.84
10    0.84
11    0.84
12    0.84
13    0.73
14    0.81
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to extend the code so that the output of the former NaN values and the value that is decisive for the new NaN values (here 0.84) are displayed in bold?

Comment: That mostly depends on your environment that you're running this in. If you're in a notebook, pandas has some styling options: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Styler-Functions

Comment: I am working with Jupiter notebook. I am able to make a column bold but not the new calculated values.. Could you tell me how it works?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

a = [0.88, 0.84, 0.26, 0.50, 1.17, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 0.73, 0.81]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df[3:] = df[3:].fillna(value=df.iloc[1, 0])
print(df)
```

```
       0
0   0.88
1   0.84
2   0.26
3   0.50
4   1.17
5   0.84
6   0.84
7   0.84
8   0.84
9   0.84
10  0.84
11  0.84
12  0.84
13  0.73
14  0.81
```

Comment: This requires the array to have the nulls start appearing exactly at index 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[0.88, 0.84, 0.26, 0.50, 1.17, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.73, 0.81]
a = np.array(a)
a[np.isnan(a)] = a[1]
a
```

results:

```
array([0.88, 0.84, 0.26, 0.5 , 1.17, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84,
       0.84, 0.84, 0.73, 0.81])
```

Comment: This requires the array to have the nulls start appearing exactly at index 5.